# How to plot the top 5 values in 'pandas.core.series.Series' in Bokeh?

Tags: python, plot, graph, bokeh

The first column contains names and the second column contains values.
how can I plot it using bokeh. here is a code below that plots in matlabplot

```
new_rf = pd.Series(rf.feature_importances_,index=x.columns).sort_values(ascending=False) 


new_rf[:5]
```

such that x will take the variable name and y will take the value

```
p =figure()

p.vbar(
x = new_rf[:5].index, #here will be the feature name
top = new_rf[:5].values, #here will be feature_importance weight
)
```

This just gives me an empty plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues with your code:

1. You create `new_rf` but use `imp_feat_rf`. I assume it was just partial renaming when copying code over to SO
2. `vbar()` requires `width` argument. You should see this error in the Python output when you run the code
3. Working with categorical data requires setting explicit categories for ranges. More details are available at https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html. Note that `x_range` argument accepts lists but it does not accept pandas indices, so you have to convert the index to a list